# How to get ForegroundAccentBrush in uwp?

Tags: uwp

In xaml code

```
Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}"
```

How to get the color in C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Changing Color through c#

```
Anything.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush"];
```

Anything is your button, text , etc. Anything which support it

> You can use Color.FromArgb() to define a custom color in code:

```
Anything.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 225, 48, 221));
```

Just change ARGB code according to your requirement

> And More if you want hex colour code in future in your app you can do this:

Create a method to Convert Hex string to SolidColorBrush:

```
public SolidColorBrush GetSolidColorBrush(string hex)
{
    hex = hex.Replace("#", string.Empty);
    byte a = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(0, 2), 16));
    byte r = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(2, 2), 16));
    byte g = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(4, 2), 16));
    byte b = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(6, 2), 16));
    SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b));
    return myBrush;
}
```

Now all that left is to get the color by Calling the method and pass the hex string to it as parameter:

```
var color = GetSolidColorBrush("#FFDC3569").Color;
```